# Why the inconsistent treatment of 'production ready' type questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

There are [lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=production+ready) essentially along the lines of "Is framework/script xxx production ready?". Some are closed as being subjective, while others are left open.

I personally had [a question of this nature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802936/fuelphp-is-it-production-ready) closed, although I already the answer I wanted so wasn't bothered.

However, when I see [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864001/is-rvm-production-ready) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433630/is-wpf-production-ready) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291950/is-objectdb-production-ready) that are not closed I'm confused. Should I be flagging these questions? Or were the mods who closed my question being overzealous?

Comment: Some may have made it under the radar, some might address more than the overall title which gave the question a little credibility, you _could_ flag them, but the action taken would differ from person to person as the standards vary vastly. If you don't care about flag weight and simply want to help the community, analyse questions individually and take instinctive action - this might make _you_ feel better, but that's likely to be the only real benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMNSHO they **should** be closed as subjective - to restate, "do you think I should use X?". Some of them haven't been closed *yet*, but you shouldn't use that as a precedent for "...and mine shouldn't be closed either".

I have checked the questions you linked to, and most of them are tragically obsolete - some projects have matured since the questions were asked, some have withered; so, there's yet another close reason for those questions: "too localized (in time)" - is it useful to know whether MySuperFrameWork 0.9.4.q was production ready in May 2009?

Note that most of those questions are just that - "it is May 2011, should I use Project XYZ 3.0?"; those are not even real questions, as the askers rarely state their needs, let alone requirements.

So, while most of these questions are closable for three different reasons, I wouldn't flag them - flags have different purpose than close votes, please don't use them as if they were interchangeable.

Comment: Now, I seem to have some unused close votes...hmm, what to do, what to do...?

Comment: Of course, for people who don't yet have close voting ability, flags *do* serve a similar function.

Comment: Now I'm really confused. I have used flags as 'poor question' because the flag box seems to suggest I should. "I am flagging this question because it doesn't belong here... because it's subjective and argumentative." Given that I see questions closed for that reason, I assumed the flag was for people (like me) who don't have close votes. PS - is there a link for 'when to use which flag?'